# Extend sap.m.Input: onAfterRendering method doesn't work

Tags: sapui5

I created a custom extension for sap.m.Input. In onAfterRendering I want to mask the value using using [jquery-maskmoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) as follows:

```
  $('#'+this.getId()+'-inner').maskMoney({ thousands : '', decimal : '.' });'
```

When I apply mask in the console, everything works fine. But when I try to 
add it in the onAfterRendering method, I get some errors when I am trying to setValue:

```
 amountInputControl.setValue(data.amount); // Its is an instance of NumericInput
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at sap.m.InputBase._getInputValue (InputBase.js:9)
    at sap.m.InputBase.updateDomValue (InputBase.js:32)
    at sap.m.InputBase.setValue (InputBase.js:34)
    at sap.ui.controller.updateFieldsForReference //Here was executed operation setValue
```

NumericInput.js

```
jQuery.sap.declare("control.customInputTypes.NumericInput");
            sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'sap/m/Input'],

                function(jQuery, BaseInput) {
                    "use strict";

                    var commonControlInput = BaseInput.extend('control.customInputTypes.NumericInput', /** @lends sap.m.Input.prototype */ {
                        metadata: {},
                        renderer : {
                            render : function(oRm, oControl) {
                                sap.m.InputRenderer.render(oRm, oControl); 
                            }
                        }
                    });

         commonControlInput.prototype.onAfterRendering = function () {
                   $('#'+this.getId()+'-inner').maskMoney({ thousands : '', decimal : '.' });
                };

            return commonControlInput;
    }, /* bExport= */ true);
```

I didn't even touch the InputBase class, so I wonder whats wrong? If I don't apply this mask everything works fine.
Maybe I cannot use jQuery in the onAfterRendering method of a control?

Comment: Can you mention the SAPUI5 version and jQuery-maskmoney version? I tried your code and did not face any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I tought you might want to check [sap.m.MaskInput](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput/preview), but I guess that's not exactly what you want...

Anyway, there are a few things I would change in your code. Here is a running [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/xitebulike/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
                xmlns:cit="control.customInputTypes">

                <cit:NumericInput value="1219999234" />

            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Custom Control ###
                // remove the first parameter in "real" apps
                sap.ui.define("control/customInputTypes/NumericInput",[
                    "jquery.sap.global",
                    "sap/m/Input",
                    "sap/m/InputRenderer"
                ], function(jQuery, Input, InputRenderer) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Input.extend("control.customInputTypes.NumericInput", {

                        init : function () {                          
                          this.addEventDelegate({
                            onAfterRendering : function(){
                              var $input = jQuery("#"+this.getId()+"-inner");
                              $input.maskMoney({
                                thousands : ".",
                                decimal : "," 
                              }).maskMoney("mask");
                            }.bind(this)
                          });
                        },

                        renderer : InputRenderer

                    });
                });

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
                ], function (Controller) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () { 

                        }
                    });
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok it works, moving onAfterRendering binding to the init method helped.

We still had problem with plugin: https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney

exactly this one
https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/issues/203

so we've used 
https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker
and everyting is working now.

Thanks for help